# Check discontinuity of a Function

Tags: calculus

could someone please help me to check discontinuity of the following Function:

[image]if
[image]

Comment: It is continuous at points $|x| \ne 1$. What about at $|x|=1$? In other words, is $f$ continuous at $x=1$ and $x=-1$?

Comment: Write everything you know about the question in your post. For example, mention any formulas (continuity criteria etc.) that you know. This will help us answer your question, and answer it better than if you just stated the question plain.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $g(x)=\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^2+1}$ is continuous everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$, since the denominator is irreducible. Also note that $g$ can differ from $f$ at at most two points, the solutions of $\vert x\vert=1$.

In particular, we must have $\lim_{x\to 1}g(x)=\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$ (and similar for $-1$).  Since $g$ is known to be continuous, we must have $g(1)=\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$.

As $f$ is continuous at 1 just in the case that $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=f(1)$, (by definition) we can check continuity at 1 simply by  that $f(1)=g(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The function is discontinuous at $x=1$. This is because, at $x=1$, $\lim_\limits{x\to 1}f(x)=\lim_\limits{x\to1}\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^2+1}=0$, whereas $f(1)=[x^2+1]_{x=1}=2$. At other points, the function is continuous as $\lim_\limits{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)\forall x_0\in\mathbb{R}-\{1\}$